# Is event-time based filtering and update of KTable possible?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

My use-case:

- receive messages with past (up to 4 years), current and **future event-time**.
- timestamp format is `YYYY-MM-DD` (i.e. truncated to midnight)
- use custom timestamp extractor to get the embedded timestamp of a message.
- `groupBy` UserId and `reduce` groups to receive latest (*max by time*) event for each user at this moment(`<Instant.now`).
- write out updated snapshots to DB or other storage.
- update KTable automatically when condition `futureEventTime < Instant.now` becomes true and previously "invisible" messages from the future become available for processing.

If I understand correctly, KTable is updated only on new messages in topic, while I need to update it at least once a day to make existing messages (with future event-time) available.

Is my use-case possible to implement with Kafka Streams without manually triggering or sending dummy messages to reprocess KTable?

Comment: I don't think this would be simple using the DSL. Using the Processor API with punctuations might work though.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Do you think "Stream Time based Punctuate with System Time based secondary expiry" approach from https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Punctuate+Use+Cases would work in this case?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking in this direction...